# Angular Google Map, lazy loading, second time

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, angular-providers

I'm using angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/

I use the recommended lazy loading technique, I have this in my app.js:

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
  uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    //    key: 'your api key',
    v: '3.20' //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
    //libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
  });
})
```

And at some point in my controller, I execute this:

```
var uiGmapGoogleMapApiTimer = $timeout(function() {
  reject("uiGmapGoogleMapApi didn't respond after 10 seconds.");
}, 5000);

console.log('DUDE.01');
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
  console.log('DUDE.02');
  $timeout.cancel(uiGmapGoogleMapApiTimer);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  resolve(geocoder);
}, function(err) {
  console.log('DUDE.03');
});
```

So, when I'm offline, the timer will kick in, and I send the user back to the login page. (Originally I simply exit the app. It works in android, but in iOS it doesnt work, it's in fact forbidden by Apple).

So... that's why now I'm sending it back to login page.

Now, in the login page, I reactivate my wifi.... and once I'm back in the page that (is supposed to) show the map.... it breaks. The success handler of uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then never gets called. (Dude.01 gets printed, but Dude.02 nor Dude.03 get printed).

So... that page (wrongly) thinks that the device is still disconnected.

I suppose it's because the loading of google map javascripts is only done once (during load -- that´s why if I close my app, and return back, things will run just fine).

So... it's not really lazy loading (?). Or... if it's lazy loading, it doesn't seem to support scenarios like... try loading it the second time (if the first time failed because of connectivity).

Is anyone familiar enough with the source code of angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/ to suggest what's the solution for this problem?

---

I looked at the logs I put in the library's code... I came to the conclusion: I need  way to get line 183 to be re-executed on the second time I call uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then ... Currently it doesn't. It only gets called the first, when I start my app, and having internet connection since the beginning.

[image]

---

And based on what I understand from this doc on "provider", I need the uiGmapGoogleMapApi to be reinstantiated (right before) the second time I try to use it.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

Is that right? How?

---

Looks like I'm battling against provider caching here. Because I use dependency injection in my controller to get reference to  uiGmapGoogleMapApi. (I have .controller('myctrl', function(uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {...})

what I  might need is:

```
.controller('myctrl', function() {
   var uiGmapGoogleMapApi = $injector.get('uiGmapGoogleMapApi');
   //or something along that line maybe
 })
```

---

I just tried it, still doesn't work.

Please help.

Thanks,
Raka

---

Well, my "solution" is: instead of going to login page, I simply refresh the app., by setting the current url of the window object to index.html.

Comment: Has any cache state of your view? Need to know **when** _reactivate my wifi.... and once I'm back in the page that (is supposed to) show the map.... it breaks. The success handler of uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then never gets called_, are you sure your controller gets called?

Comment: yes, i'm sure i put console.log betwwen the lines